# Média entre posições de dois vetores

Tags: python

Galera, como posso fazer a média entre posicoes de n vetores?Por exemplo, dado um vetor de entrada da forma

```
 vet = [[10,10,10,10],[10,20,10,10],[10,15,10,10]]
```

Preciso que a funcao retorne um novo vetor com a media dos valores de cada posicao de cada vetor, ou seja:

```
res = [(10+10+10)/3, (10+20+15)/3,...]
```

A primeira posição do vetor resultante será a média das primeiras posições dos subvetores do vetor de entrada, a segunda posição do vetor resultante será a média dos valores das segundas posições dos subvetores de entrada e assim por diante!

Estou programando em python!

Comment: Na verdade o que preciso é a média entre, por exemplo: média entre a primeira posicao dos 3 vetores, depois a media entre os valores das segundas posicoes entre os vetores, e assim por diante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for garantido que todas as listas possuem o mesmo número de elementos, você pode utilizar a função `zip` para gerar as listas com os valores de cada posição, calculando a média fazendo a divisão entre a soma e a quantidade de elementos:

```
from statistics import mean

res = [mean(values) for values in zip(*vet)]
```

Isso gerará a lista `[10, 15, 10, 10]`.

Comment: Era EXATAMENTE isso que eu procurava! Obrigado!!!